# My computer is not turning on

Tags: hardware-failure, charging, charger

I'm not sure I'm on the right site, but I really need help.
I got today a laptop dell core i7 10th generation. I put it on charger. At first it was charging normally. I went away for a few hours, and I when I returned, I found the computer's light turned off (that light that turns on when plugged in). I thought it was fully charged, but when I tried to turn it on, it did not turn on at all. The light on the cable turns on when I plug the charger to the wall socket, but the laptop's light doesn't turn on, and the laptop doesn't turn on either. Please help.

Does anyone have any idea what must be wrong with my laptop?

Comment: We don't have enough information to guess. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Before sending to repair, try pressing the power button for a long time (> 1min) to see if it procudes any response.

Comment: @eduardo bissi thank you loads! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the computer sounds new, I suggest to have it replaced on warranty.

It's possible that an electrical surge has fried the computer in your absence
(but don't mention this possibility when asking for replacement).
If the electricity is unstable in your neighborhood, I suggest getting a
surge-protector or even an uninterrupted Power Supply (UPS).